# HVX Camera Streaming (Hexagon SDK) is not working in Intrinsyc Qualcomm Snapdtragon 845 uSOM Dev. Kit

Tags: qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

I have been practicing sample codes of Hexagon DSP SDK on Intrinsyc  Open-Q™ 845 uSOM Hardware Development Kit. when i have tried with the camera streaming example i was able to execute the code and run it in DSP, even though i'm not getting a valid output. The intended output is pixel data processing effects. For the hvx_add_constant example, the bright area will periodically be boosted to pink color. But I got an output with no preview image when the camera opened, just like a black window.

Thanks in advance.